# system() returns error but shell() works

Tags: r, windows

I've recently done a (Windows) system update and now I cannot run system commands anymore using R. I've tried to reinstall R and all the used packages but this doesn't resolve my problem. Rebooting also didn't solve the problem.

I just discovered that while the system() and system2() commands don't work anymore, the shell() command does work.

```
> system('ECHO "test"')
Warning message:
running command 'ECHO "test"' had status 127
> system2('ECHO "test"')
Warning message:
running command 'ECHO \"test\"' had status 127
> shell('ECHO "test"')
"test"
```

The documentation describes that shell() should be a simple user-friendly wrapper around system(). Therefore I don't understand why shell() works, but system doesn't.

With another computer on which the system() functions still work, I've checked for differences. The Windows version, the R version and the package versions are equal (at least according to sessionInfo() in a clean session). Shell() specifies a few additional arguments compared to system() with which I could play:

- **shell** specifies the shell to be used. The 'Details' section tells me that this will check two environment variables: R_SHELL and COMSPEC. R_SHELL is not defined on both systems (global and local). COMSPEC is defined and refers on both systems to cmd.exe (in the same folder). I've checked and running the pure command via this executable works.
- **flag** no idea what this does, but it is a difference with the system() command. As far as I understand it, the only reason to change it would be when a different shell/OS is used (e.g. Bash on Linux).
- **intern** set to FALSE for both shell() and system().
- **wait** set to TRUE for both shell() and system().
- **translate** set to TRUE, but the system call doesn't contain '/' nor '\'. As expected, playing with this Boolean doesn't change the results.
- **mustWork** related to the output in case of an error. Will return an error or a warning. Changing this Boolean doesn't change the behavior.

Therefore, I can only conclude that shell() does something on top of system() that somehow changes its behavior. This behavior is not specified in the documentation, nor accessible via any of the arguments.

Where could I look for additional differences between both in order to find the source of this bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I tried if I can reproduce this (on Win10):

```
system('ECHO "test"')
#Warning message:
#running command 'ECHO "test"' had status 127

shell('ECHO "test"')
#"test"
```

Then I looked at `shell`'s source code and discovered that it changes the command before passing it to `system`. On my system:

```
system('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c ECHO "test"')
#"test"
```

See also `Sys.getenv("COMSPEC")` which gives the shell if `Sys.getenv("R_SHELL")` is empty. Note that the documentation states that the POSIX standards require running commands under a shell. `help("system")` explains that on a Unix-alike OS `system` launches a shell and recommends `shell` (on Windows).

Comment: The thing that really confused me was that it did work on another computer. Apparently, that computer has echo.exe which does exactly what it says (installed via Rtools and automatically added to the path). Therefore I didn't realize that system doesn't pass via the shell (cmd).